# How do I insert a comma before a date in an URL?

Tags: excel, csv

So I have approx. 8.000 URLs, and most of them are missing a comma before their date-part, and I need that damn comma to pass my undergrad.

Examples:

(...)`_employee_declarations_legal_complaint_and_motions_2009` (should be: motions,_2009)
(...)`/wiki/Xinhua_Presidential_Express_18_Jun_2009` (should be: Express,_18_Jun_2009)
(...)`guide_for_law_enforcement_23_Dec_2008` (should be: enforcement,_23_Dec_2008)

And so on. I need to insert the commas automatically in Excel. Is that even possible? Could you tell it to insert a comma before a ## _ text _ #### or something like that? Replace won't work, when it's different dates.

The biggest problem is, that I'm not a programmer. I'm an undergraduate political science major trying to do a statistical analysis of WikiLeaks.

BTW: The problem is not that I imported it wrong (from CSV to Excel), there's lots of commas other places. The problem is that I use import.io as a datascraper, and it's probably their bug.

Comment: If they were all formatted  in the `_23_Dec_2008` format (with the day always being 2 digits) I'd say you could do it with excel, but if you have inconsistent formatting I think you'll need to use some other tool

Comment: Yeah, their not all like that. But if there's only >20 formats, then I'll just do it again and again. If it's the _23_Dec_2008 format (two digits, text and then four digits) how would you then do it in excel?

Comment: One thing you may not have considered is that the entire value *must* be subsequently wrapped in text identifiers like double quotes or the field value becomes two fields. If you bring it into Excel you can use VBA to repair it and export back to .CSV it with double-quotes as text identifiers wrapping each field that could potentially contain a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a text editor on your CSV file (if it supports Perl-style regexes) and tell it to replace

```
_(?:\d{1,2}_[A-Za-z]{3}_)?(?:19|20)\d{2}\b
```

with `,\0`.

Comment: It may be that your editor needs a different backreference syntax instead of `\0` which contains the matched text of the regex in editors like UltraEdit or EditPad Pro.

Comment: This is probably what I should do, but I have no idea how to run regexes - haven't learned it, and I don't have time before my deadline. That's why I desperately need to do it in excel.

Answer (score 0):

If the majority are in the format i.e. '_23_Dec_2008', I assuming the date is always at the end of the string.. try

> ```
> =REPLACE(A1,FIND(RIGHT(A1,12),A1,0,",")
> ```

1. The 12 refers to the number of characters in the date i.e. date format '_23_Dec_2008' is 12
2. The 1 refers to the start character of the string to be amended i.e. from _
3. The 0 refers to the number of characters to amend i.e. none
4. The "," adds the comma in front of the underscore

Just need to amend first row to those dates of different lengths

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you've mentioned that there are about twenty different formats. Here are three (two because your sample was ambiguous about *d* vs. *dd*).

```
Sub fix_urls()
    Dim fw As String, rw As String, i As Long, iOldCalc As Long

    On Error GoTo Fìn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        'replace the days both ways as the sample data was ambiguous
        For i = 1 To 31
            fw = Format(i, "_00_")  'find what
            rw = Format(i, "\,_00_")  'replace with
             .Replace What:=fw, Replacement:=rw, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
            fw = Format(i, "_0_")  'find what
            rw = Format(i, "\,_0_")  'replace with
             .Replace What:=fw, Replacement:=rw, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        Next i
        For i = 2000 To 2014
            fw = Format(i, "_0000")  'find what
            rw = Format(i, "\,_0000")  'replace with
             .Replace What:=fw, Replacement:=rw, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        Next i
    End With

Fìn:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Plan your attack carefully. Look closely at the twenty-odd formats and make sure that one could not supercede a false positive on another. Often there is a prescribed order that replacements must be performed in.

For example, in the three format masks used above, if the *_dd_* was only *_dd* then *_20* with `xlPart` would supercede any *_2000*, *_2001*, *_2002*, etc. Just be careful and keep a few backups.

Just a reminder to my comment above; with these inserted commas you need to use a *text qualifier* so that a comma in the middle of a text field does not break that field's value into two fields. Excel *should* do this for you on a simple `Save As ► .CSV` but it looks into the data a preset number of rows to determine whether or not to use quoted identifiers on a field. This *look-ahead* value can be raised through the registry but that is generally not necessary.